# How to digitally sign a PDF(or another document) in Java?

Tags: pdf, cryptography, sign

What libraries can be used to digitally sign documents in Java?

Answer (score 6):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) is probably the highest quality PDF manipulation library I've seen commercial or open source, and it absolutely can be used to sign PDF documents.

- [From the documentation](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#howtosign).
- [A blog entry describing how it's done](http://itext.ugent.be/articles/eid-pdf/).

Answer (score 2):

Because PDF has explicit support for digital signatures, the process for signing them is different than what you might have to use for "another document", as [pointed out already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935010/how-to-digitally-sign-a-pdfor-another-document-in-java/935072#935072).

If you have a document format that doesn't have digital signature support "built-in", you can wrap it with in another format that supports digital signatures, such as S/MIME. [BouncyCastle's S/MIME support](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/mdocs1.5/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/package-summary.html) is alright.

Answer (score 1):

The [iText](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/) website has a [section](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#howtosign) specifically addressing this scenario.